# MySQL: poor performance joining small to large table

Tags: mysql, performance, join, inner-join

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE smalltable (
    smalltable_id VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    bigtable_id VARCHAR(64),
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (smalltable_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE bigtable (
    bigtable_id VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    count BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (bigtable_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

`smalltable` has about 8000 rows and `bigtable` about 40 million. I would like to retrieve those rows from `smalltable` where `smalltable.bigtable_id` is present in `bigtable`. The following query took almost 10 hours to complete:

```
SELECT * FROM smalltable
INNER JOIN bigtable
ON smalltable.bigtable_id = bigtable.bigtable_id;
```

Here is the output of `EXPLAIN`:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: smalltable
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 8610
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: bigtable
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 38818260
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

I'm no expert in interpreting this, but it looks like MySQL is doing a sequential scan over both tables. If I write a little Python script that iterates over all rows in `smalltable` and executes a `SELECT` query on `bigtable` for each row in `smalltable` the whole thing finishes in 25 seconds. I'd like to have the same kind of performance with a single SQL query.

Comment: Add an index on smalltable (bigtable_id)

Comment: Thanks. That does indeed speed things up considerably. The query now takes 1min 30sec. Still slower than manually iterating over smalltable and firing off select queries to bigtable, though. Also, it would be nice to have a solution that doesn't require altering smalltable. In the actual use-case the data in smalltable is a subset of another big table and I don't have write permissions for that one.

Comment: Indexes are where it's at. The alternative is to do what you're already doing.

Comment: Check the `COLLATION` of `bigtable_id` in both tables -- it must be the same.

Comment: What is the setting of `join_buffer_size`?  What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Check the optimizer path, which table is the main source, as if it is slow, the bigtable is used as the main source. try this:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN * FROM smalltable
INNER JOIN bigtable
ON smalltable.bigtable_id = bigtable.bigtable_id;
```

Using STRAIGHT_JOIN will tell mysql to follow the order of tables in your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the info from `smalltable` (which is what your description implies),

```
SELECT *
    FROM smalltable AS s
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
            FROM bigtable
            WHERE bigtable_id = s.bigtable_id );
```